# android.support.design.CoordinatorLayout class not found

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I got the following crash when integrating the new design library and didn't found a workaround yet:

**Error inflating class android.support.design.CoordinatorLayout**

Here is my gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

...and the app style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#cccccc</item>
</style>
```

`public class TabbedScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in the `android.support.design.widget` package. Inflate the `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: wow, after mucking around w/ different versions of the support libraries in `dependencies`, this was the actual problem.. in my layout I replaced `<CoordinatorLayout>` with `<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>` and now it runs.

Answer (score -1):

The above answer is right also ensure that you have the dependencies matching your buildtoolsversion

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

I did this and it worked for me..